# How to "wait" setTimeout to finish inside function and then execute function's return

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, dom, load

In function, `const htmlCollection = document.getElemenetsByClassName('elemenet-class')` is used to get desired element from DOM and some element's properties are used in return value of function (`return htmlCollection[0].clientWidth`).

The problem was that function's return executes before all DOM nodes are loaded so when I access `htmlCollection[0]` to get desired `element`, it gets `undefined`. What I tried is wrapping code inside `setTimeout` with `500ms` offset where I can access `htmlCollection[0]` element but now problem is that function's return is part of main thread and executes before whole `setTimeout` which is asynchronous operation, so `htmlCollection[0].clientWidth` which should be in return value of function "lives" only inside `setTimeout`.

How can I "wait" for DOM to be loaded (or "wait" setTimeout to execute and retrieve `contentWrapperWidth`) and then execute function's return?

Code:

```js
// first try (fails because on function return, 'content-wrapper' is not loaded in DOM)
renderPreview = () => {
let htmlString = getHTML();
const contentWrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('content-wrapper');
const contentWrapperWidth = contentWrapper[0].clientWidth;

htmlString = htmlString.replace('width_placeholder', contentWrapperWidth);

return htmlString;
}


// second try (fails because function's return executes before setTimeout of course - i.e. contentWrapperWidth lives only inside setTimeout and function returns htmlString with placeholder, before replacing)
renderPreview = () => {
let htmlString = getHTML();

setTimeout(() => {
const contentWrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('content-wrapper');
const contentWrapperWidth = contentWrapper[0].clientWidth;

htmlString = htmlString.replace('width_placeholder', contentWrapperWidth);
} , 500);

return htmlString;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `document.addEventListener("load", function)`

that should load your function after the dom loads.

Comment: Tried it already, doesn't work. Added `console.log` inside `addEventListener` callback and it doesn't fire. Probably main function's return executes first again.